# iOS - Print and store array of dictionary in swift 3

Tags: ios, arrays, dictionary

In my project I have an array of dictionaries:

```
var list = [[String: Any]] ()
```

Very briefly, what I do is download a JSON file from a URL

```
//        json parsing 2
        let url:String = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users"
        let urlRequest = URL(string: url)
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: urlRequest!, completionHandler: {(data, response, error) in
            if(error != nil)
            {
                print(error.debugDescription)
            }else{
                do {
                    self.list = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .allowFragments)
                        as! [[String: Any]]
                    OperationQueue.main.addOperation {
                        self.tableView.reloadData()
                    }
                }catch let error as NSError{
                    print(error)
                }
            }
        }).resume()
```

Now, within the **list** (which is an array of dictionaries) I have all the data that interest me. But if I want to pick out a single value, or print the entire contents of **list** how am I supposed to do?

> EDIT: also, I can **simplify** the structure and do not use an array
>   of dictionaries, but something simpler?

Comment: More information is needed. If you write down the JSON you want to parse and what you want to do with it in an example maybe we can refer you to the solution.

Comment: but for the cell is easy right, it is just like self.list[indexPath.row]["yourKey"]

Comment: Please take a look at SwiftyJSON.  https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON  It will simplify this type of task.

Comment: @AitorPagán the json file I download, I have to represent in a tableView, this part I have already settled with                                                              `let item = self. list [indexPath.row]
        Mobile textLabel?. text = this ["name"] as? String
        Mobile detailTextLabel?. text = this ["email"] as? String` in func of tableView..My problem is to print the array of dictionaries or access it

Comment: @Matteo as @Retterdesdialogs said, you can access them by the index of the array. But what I say is that if you can write the JSON just to have the reference of what you are working with. You can print it using the print method `print(array)`

Comment: @AitorPagán But if I wanted to save the array of dictionaries can I use userdefault?

Comment: @Matteo yes you can. I dont know the key of the json that contains the array of Dictionary but this is the way I would do it:

`let results = object["key"] as? [[String: Any]] 
UserDefaults.standard.set(cart, forKey: "thekeyIWantToStore")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Or you can use archiving

```
import Foundation

class UserDataManager {

var documentsURL: NSURL?
var fileURL:NSURL?

func setFileURL(file: String) {
    documentsURL = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory,
                                                   in: .userDomainMask)[0] as NSURL?
    fileURL = documentsURL!.appendingPathComponent(file) as NSURL?

}

func write(file: String, mDict: NSDictionary) {
    setFileURL(file: file)
    let data : NSData = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: mDict) as NSData
    if let fileAssigend = fileURL {
        data.write(to: fileAssigend as URL, atomically: true)
    }
}

func read(file: String) -> NSDictionary {
    setFileURL(file: file)

    var data:NSData?
    if let url = fileURL {
        data =  NSData(contentsOf: url as URL)
        if let result = data {
            return NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObject(with: result as Data) as! NSDictionary
        }
    }

    let dict = NSDictionary()

    return dict
}
}
```

and use it with

write:

```
        let userDataManager = UserDataManager()
        userDataManager.write(file: "userDataDict", mDict: responseObject)
```

read:

```
        let userDataManager = UserDataManager()
        let userDataDict = userDataManager.read(file: "userDataDict")
```